# Are objects that have no state always visible when published?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility, safe-publication

Say I have a class

```
public class Foo {
    public void printHi() {
       System.out.print("Hi");
    }
}
```

and in some client code I do something like

```
public static void main() {
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     (new Thread(() -> {foo.printHi();})).start();
}
```

and take away the happens-before guarantee for calling Thread Start.
Then is it possible that the Foo reference might not be visible to that thread using it or worse, the method that belongs to that class is not visible, but the Foo reference is visible. I am not sure how method is stored in an object like fields, but this assumes that it is just something in memory belonging to that object, so it might have visibility issues, but that I am not sure of. Can someone also explain that part to me?

I ask this because Foo is immutable, and in the JCIP book Goetz says that

**"Immutable objects, on the other hand, can be safely accessed even when synchronization is not used to publish the object reference. For this guarantee of initialization safety to hold, all of the requirements for immutability must be met: unmodi-fiable state, all fields are final, and proper construction"** (Goetz, 3.5.2)

However, it doesn't have any final fields, so does it count as if all fields are final? Since no fields = all fields?

Comment: "all fields are final" means "no fields are non-final". It is vacuuosly true when you have no fields.

Comment: Note that `Foo` isn't technically immutable because it is extendable (and thus a subclass could be created which has mutable fields): make it final and/or add a private constructor.

Comment: Ahh thanks for that confirmation. That makes sense on the subclassing, but in terms of the JMM guarantee that if this class is properly constructed, it can be safely shared and visible, does that still hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to get to the same answer.

1. Your object is immutable, as it bears no state that can be modified.
2. All of its fields are `final`, as there is no field that is not `final`.
3. There is no possible race condition, as there are no data that could be modified while being accessed.
4. Even if there were some non-`final` fields declared in `Foo`, the invocation of `printHi()`, which does not read the object’s state, bears no potential data race. Note that this only applies to exact instances of `Foo`, produced by `new Foo(…)` expressions, as subclasses could override `printHi()` to access shared mutable state.

   It’s important to emphasize that race condition are about the shared mutable data, not necessarily objects. So if `printHi()` accesses a shared `static` variable of a different class, it could produce a data race, even if the `Foo` instance is immutable and/or properly published. The code invoking `foo.printHi()` in another thread is safe, if `printHi()` does not access shared mutable state (or only using proper guarding).

As [Elliott Frisch mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48055521/2711488), a lambda expression behaves like an immutable object anyway, so the code would be safe even without the *happens-before* relationship of `Thread.start()` or the immutability of `Foo` (assuming the `Foo` instance is not modified afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

`foo` **must be** (effectively) `final` to use here.

```
Foo foo = null; // <-- for example,
foo = new Foo();
(new Thread(() -> {
    foo.printHi(); // <-- compiler error
})).start();
```

Comment: Ah yes, the Java 8 Lambda effectively final compile check. But please see the updated and edited question, I think that the question I was trying to ask wasn't conveyed properly, but now it is

Comment: @katiex7 The key is **effectively**. If the fields don't change, then yes; it is *effectively* immutable.

Comment: so does that have the same guarantee under the JMM for safe publication and visibility?